# how to stop the system .service using aws iot job

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, iot, aws-cli, aws-iot

i'm trying to stop service which is running in my iot device through aws-iot job
for this purpose. i follow this **link** https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js to start,stop and restart my service

through this link i can able to reboot my iot device, likewise i  also need to start,stop and restart the service which running in iot device.

service name would look like **soucefileName.service**.

manually i'm starting this service by, `sudo systemctl start service`. i want to achieve this by job.

i run this code in command line using aws cli https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot/create-job.html

```
aws iot create-job --job-id "jobname"  --targets "aws-arn/thingname" --document '{"operation": "stop","packageName": "sourcefilename.service"}'
```

i didn't get any error but my service is not stopped.and also not able to understand what is **package name** in above code.

if any one have solution share with me. thanks in advance